# Android service need onStop() method to stop running worker thread

Tags: android, service, callback

I have this problem. I have been looking around for answers, but to my surprise I can't find any good ones.

I have a service which starts a new worker thread in `onStartCommand()` when `startService()` is called. Now I want to shut down the worker thread in the service when I call `stopService()`, but there is no `onStop()` method. `onDestroy()` doesn't get called either. Someone said that I need to use `onStartCommand()` with some special args in order to stop my service, but that seems totally backward!

Once and for all: Why is there no `onStop()` method inside the Service class?

How do I shut down my worker thread that resides inside the Service class?

Also: where does the intent in `stopService(Intent intent)` go? Can I catch it?

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to bind to the `Service` - in that way you can directly call methods.

Comment: I still don't understand why I need to bind the service. A lot of extra work for nothing kind of...

Comment: **"I still don't understand why I need to bind the service."** Because you need to control it. A worker thread is not an inherent part of the standard `Service` class and as such it's an 'extra' aspect which you have added. Just to clarify, I suspect the `Service` class doesn't have an `onStop()` method because multiple app components can call `startService` or bind to it in order to use it - if `onStop()` was available and basically shutdown it's operation, it would break things for other app components.

Comment: Also, `onDestroy()` isn't called immediately because the `Service` app component is the longest living multi-use of the general Android components. If it was destroyed immediately and another component (e.g., `Activity`) wanted to use it straight away there'd be potentially a lot of overheads involved in destroy -> recreate. Binding doesn't require a lot of work maybe a dozen or so extra lines of code and it will give you absolute control.

Comment: How does unbindService(serviceConnection) know from which service to unbind? I mean serviceConnection doesn't contain that info(!?) Can an activity only bind to one service simultaneously?